# Nyaya starter works

Tags: nyaya

Wondering if there is any good introductory Nyaya works that are short, but breakdown the crux of Nyaya sutras. PDF formatting or website links. English translations are useful, but I need the original Sanskrit verses.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151065/discussion-on-question-by-haridasa-nyaya-starter-works); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.